# jQuery Hide A Scrolling Div If a Tab is Active

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this jQuery code to show a scrolling div after x pixels.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 1000) {
        jQuery('.vmenu').fadeIn();
    } else {
        jQuery('.vmenu').fadeOut();
    }

});
```

However I need to hide `.vmenu` if a tab is active on the page. The theme automatically applies `x-active` class, if the tab is active.

```
<div id="panel-8" class="x-tabs-panel x-active"> ... </div>
```

So I have tried this jQuery code but it doesnt work.

```
if(jQuery('#panel-8.x-active').length){
   jQuery('.vmenu').hide();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This may help you.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 1000) {
    jQuery('.vmenu').fadeIn();
    if(jQuery('#panel-8').hasClass('.x-active')){
      jQuery('.vmenu').hide();
    };
  } else {
    jQuery('.vmenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: could I have only 1 IF condition with 2 statements y > 1000 and not panel-8.active ?

Comment: Try @Dimitris answer and let me know. Like to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying that?

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 1000 && !jQuery('#panel-8').hasClass('x-active')) {
    jQuery('.vmenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    jQuery('.vmenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```